# Laptop not booting and internet died before

Tags: boot, internet

So I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my laptop about a week ago. It worked fine (after some weird ACPI issues which fixed themselves...) Then the internet died. It would connect, but not actually **connect**... If you see what I mean... I could do ping 8.8.8.8 and it would work... But ping www.google.com did not. Then, I thought I would go onto my 16.04lts live USB and see if the internet worked on that. Then I could not boot from that. Thinking this was weird, I went to boot from my HDD. Boom. I get the error "A start job is running for Hold until boot process finishes up (58s / no limit)"... This happens after the ubuntu loading screen with the little dots. The laptop is an MSI GL62M 7RD with an i5 7300HQ and a 1050.

Thanks in advance for helping...

James

Comment: The first problem was with DNS - your DNS was not working so you could ping 8.8.8.8 but not connect to google.com . Set your DNS in network manager.

Comment: ok, but how do i make the thing boot?

Comment: No Idea. I would do a fresh install of either 18.04 or 17.10